# Dynamically add dropdownlist to table by using append()

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Can i add dropdownlist to table by using jquery append.

Eg.

```
$(#table).append("<tr><td>@Html.DropDownList('TP',new SelectList(@Model.RefList, 'Value', 'Text',@Model.Ref))</td></tr>");
```

I dont known how to change this "@Html.Dropdownlist" to valid string.

Comment: Just inspect the html generated by the `Html.DropDownList()` method and copy it. But it would probably be easier to include it in the view inside a hidden element, and then clone it and append theclone

Comment: Change the razor to html

Answer (score 0):

you cannot add a server control with javascript, you can add an HTML select and load the options using `ajax`

```
$('#table').append('<select id="mySelect"></select>');
```

Example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "myServiceURL"
}).done(function(myOptions) {

    $.each(myOptions, function(key, value) {   

        $('#mySelect')
            .append($("<option></option>")
                .attr("value",key)
                .text(value)); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This Code will append Select menu to the last row of the table.

```
var select_list = '<select id="list">';
//you can add more options by repeating the next line & change text,value
select_list += '<option value="changevalue">change text</option>';
select_list += '</select>';
$("#table").append("<tr><td>"+select_list+"</td></tr>");
```